# Create DBMS_JOB in trigger to send notification to logger

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have tried my best to do this on my own, but I'm getting no where. Here is my trigger definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER KK_BUDGET_TYPE_TR AFTER
  INSERT OR
  UPDATE OR
  DELETE ON PS_KK_BUDGET_TYPE FOR EACH ROW DECLARE V_AUDIT_OPRID VARCHAR2(64);

  V_JOB_NUMBER NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.READ_CLIENT_INFO(V_AUDIT_OPRID);
    IF INSERTING THEN
      INSERT
      INTO PS_KK_BD_TYPE_AUD VALUES
        (
          GET_PS_OPRID(V_AUDIT_OPRID),
          SYSDATE,
          'A',
          :NEW.SETID1,
          :NEW.LEDGER_GROUP,
          :NEW.EFFDT,
          :NEW.EFF_STATUS,
          :NEW.CNTRL_OPTN,
          :NEW.BUDGET_STATUS,
          :NEW.DESCR,
          :NEW.BUDG_TYPE,
          :NEW.ASSOC_EXP_BD,
          :NEW.PARENT_BUDGET,
          :NEW.CHILD_EXCEED,
          :NEW.CONTROL_CHARTFIELD,
          :NEW.ALL_VALUES,
          :NEW.FILTER_CHARTFIELD,
          :NEW.TREE_NAME,
          :NEW.TREE_LEVEL,
          :NEW.ENABLE_FS,
          :NEW.KK_REV_TRACK_LG,
          :NEW.TOLERANCE,
          :NEW.BALANCED_LINES,
          :NEW.KK_ENABLE_STAT,
          :NEW.SUBTYPE,
          :NEW.EXPIRE_CHARTFIELD
        );
    ELSE
      IF DELETING THEN
        INSERT
        INTO PS_KK_BD_TYPE_AUD VALUES
          (
            GET_PS_OPRID(V_AUDIT_OPRID),
            SYSDATE,
            'D',
            :OLD.SETID1,
            :OLD.LEDGER_GROUP,
            :OLD.EFFDT,
            :OLD.EFF_STATUS,
            :OLD.CNTRL_OPTN,
            :OLD.BUDGET_STATUS,
            :OLD.DESCR,
            :OLD.BUDG_TYPE,
            :OLD.ASSOC_EXP_BD,
            :OLD.PARENT_BUDGET,
            :OLD.CHILD_EXCEED,
            :OLD.CONTROL_CHARTFIELD,
            :OLD.ALL_VALUES,
            :OLD.FILTER_CHARTFIELD,
            :OLD.TREE_NAME,
            :OLD.TREE_LEVEL,
            :OLD.ENABLE_FS,
            :OLD.KK_REV_TRACK_LG,
            :OLD.TOLERANCE,
            :OLD.BALANCED_LINES,
            :OLD.KK_ENABLE_STAT,
            :OLD.SUBTYPE,
            :OLD.EXPIRE_CHARTFIELD
          );
      ELSE
        INSERT
        INTO PS_KK_BD_TYPE_AUD VALUES
          (
            GET_PS_OPRID(V_AUDIT_OPRID),
            SYSDATE,
            'K',
            :OLD.SETID1,
            :OLD.LEDGER_GROUP,
            :OLD.EFFDT,
            :OLD.EFF_STATUS,
            :OLD.CNTRL_OPTN,
            :OLD.BUDGET_STATUS,
            :OLD.DESCR,
            :OLD.BUDG_TYPE,
            :OLD.ASSOC_EXP_BD,
            :OLD.PARENT_BUDGET,
            :OLD.CHILD_EXCEED,
            :OLD.CONTROL_CHARTFIELD,
            :OLD.ALL_VALUES,
            :OLD.FILTER_CHARTFIELD,
            :OLD.TREE_NAME,
            :OLD.TREE_LEVEL,
            :OLD.ENABLE_FS,
            :OLD.KK_REV_TRACK_LG,
            :OLD.TOLERANCE,
            :OLD.BALANCED_LINES,
            :OLD.KK_ENABLE_STAT,
            :OLD.SUBTYPE,
            :OLD.EXPIRE_CHARTFIELD
          );
        INSERT
        INTO PS_KK_BD_TYPE_AUD VALUES
          (
            GET_PS_OPRID(V_AUDIT_OPRID),
            SYSDATE,
            'N',
            :NEW.SETID1,
            :NEW.LEDGER_GROUP,
            :NEW.EFFDT,
            :NEW.EFF_STATUS,
            :NEW.CNTRL_OPTN,
            :NEW.BUDGET_STATUS,
            :NEW.DESCR,
            :NEW.BUDG_TYPE,
            :NEW.ASSOC_EXP_BD,
            :NEW.PARENT_BUDGET,
            :NEW.CHILD_EXCEED,
            :NEW.CONTROL_CHARTFIELD,
            :NEW.ALL_VALUES,
            :NEW.FILTER_CHARTFIELD,
            :NEW.TREE_NAME,
            :NEW.TREE_LEVEL,
            :NEW.ENABLE_FS,
            :NEW.KK_REV_TRACK_LG,
            :NEW.TOLERANCE,
            :NEW.BALANCED_LINES,
            :NEW.KK_ENABLE_STAT,
            :NEW.SUBTYPE,
            :NEW.EXPIRE_CHARTFIELD
          );
      END IF;
    END IF;
    DBMS_JOB.submit
    (
      job => V_JOB_NUMBER, what => 'logger "KK_BD_TYPE_AUD_CHG"', next_date => SYSDATE
    )
    ;
  END KK_BUDGET_TYPE_TR;
```

All "this is a terrible idea because of commit issues" aside, this is exactly what we want to happen, even if a rollback occurs, etc. Some code somewhere is updating a table that the some users should not be able to update. We are completely unable to determine what users are doing so we can replicate the issue, so our current goal is to get an immediate notification that data has been changed on a specific table, which would then allow us to contact the user immediately to find out what they were doing at the time. The system admin wants to put a filter on syslog so he wants me to run a command line with the following line

```
logger "KK_BD_TYPE_AUD_CHG"
```

The result is

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 100:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "KK_BD_TYPE_AUD_CHG" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ;
The symbol "; was inserted before "KK_BD_TYPE_AUD_CHG" to continue.
```

So at this point I'm at a loss and I'm out of my element. Any help, or an alternate option would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `logger` supposed to be a stored procedure?  Or is it supposed to be an executable sitting on the host operating system?  Or is it supposed to be something else?

Comment: It is an executable on the OS that provides an interface to the system log.

Comment: This is probably also a terrible idea but what you're doing seems really over-complicated. Why not just e-mail yourselves the [username](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions184.htm#sthref1594) performing the update and the [query being run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237916/how-can-i-see-queries-that-are-executed-against-oracle)?

Comment: who said "this is a terrible idea because of commit issues"? Calling DBMS_JOB.submit from a trigger is not a bad idea, at least not for this reason, since the job will be submitted/rolledback depending on whether the triggering statement is committed or rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

Since `logger` is an operating system executable, you can't call it directly from PL/SQL so you can't call it directly from `dbms_job`.

You could create a Java stored procedure that would call out to the operating system using the Java operating system API, grant appropriate privileges on that Java stored procedure to the Oracle owner, create a PL/SQL wrapper on the Java stored procedure, and then call that PL/SQL wrapper from `dbms_job`.  That would be a fair number of moving pieces but there are multiple examples online of doing this.  This [askTom question on a Java stored procedure that calls out to the host operating system](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:952229840241) is probably the best of the examples.  Be aware, though, that if you allow the caller to pass an arbitrary call, an attacker could use that to run any operating system command they would like as whatever operating system user runs the Oracle database on the host operating system.  That would allow an attacker that was able to call your procedure to do essentially anything they wanted in or to your database so it's a serious security issue.

It would be fewer moving parts to call out to the host operating system using `dbms_scheduler` rather than `dbms_job`-- here is an example of [creating and calling an executable program from dbms_scheduler](http://www.red-database-security.com/tutorial/run_os_commands_via_dbms_scheduler.html).  But you can't create a `dbms_scheduler` log in a trigger since doing so requires implicit commits.  You could work around that in your case by declaring your trigger as an autonomous transaction.  Normally, that wouldn't be an option but since it sounds like you're not concerned about getting alerts when the transaction is rolled back, that may be a reasonable option for you.

Comment: The `dbms_scheduler`  call and the implicit commit could be moved into a stored procedure that uses an autonomous transaction and is called from the trigger, thus there wouldn't be a commit in the trigger.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - A stored procedure that did an implicit commit would itself have to be defined as an autonomous transaction in order to call it from a row-level trigger, though.  You'd just be moving the `pragma autononomous_transaction` call, not eliminating it.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but it would at least move the commit out of the trigger context, wouldn't it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - It would.  It's just not obvious to me how that simplifies the solution.  Whether you have an autonomous transaction in the trigger or in a procedure called by the trigger, you have the same issues with transaction boundaries, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion with the java classes and wrapper procedure. I put one together that would just fire off the logger command with a string passed as parameter, and sent it up to our admin so he could see the options. He then told me he won't install java on the machine and he doesn't want to go through all of these hoops, so he's going to let me create another table and insert a row there, and then ping the table every minute and fire off an email when he finds a row. I'll update with more info if we get something in place (or if not)