# See all the SQL statements executed in Oracle DB 12c

Tags: sql, database, oracle, audit

I'm an administrator of DB with DBA role. So I need to gather all the SQL statements executed in DB in all sessions. Does anyone know if there is a command that shows a list of username and SQL statement executed by him? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237916/how-can-i-see-queries-that-are-executed-against-oracle

Comment: Can I ask why you need to see all the SQL statements?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you can get to that is by querying DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY.
If sessions did not matter to your requirements, you could query DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT.
both required diagnostic pack license